# CakePHP 301 redirect old URL to friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, routes

I have 2 addresses of the same page (old link and friendly URL link) and both work great! However I need to redirect old link by 301: /instrumenty/show_id/:id to /instrumenty/show/:id-:slug because of SEO (I get :slug argument from 2 fields from database).

I can do this by one line for every page in .htaccess... but it isn't rather good idea ( I have 1000+ these pages).
I tried something like this (in routes.php), but I have no idea how can I get my slug (2 fields from database)

```
Router::redirect(
    '/instrumenty/show/:id-:slug', 
    array('controller' => 'instruments', 'action' => 'show_id' /* :id and :slug here? how? */),
    array('pass' => array('id','slug'), 'status' => '301')       
);
```

Comment: Try .htaccess, meeeen

Comment: 1000 lines like this one:
Redirect 301 /instrumenty/show_id/503 /instrumenty/show/503-my-great-title-slug
Really? It can be done in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to access database and insert :slug in every redirect link. If you need this just for SEO then redirect '/instrumenty/show_id/:id' to '/instruments/show/:id' and insert [canonical tag](http://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps) into each HTML page:

```
echo "<link rel='canonical' href='/instruments/show/$id-$slug' />";
```

In routes you will have something like this:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/instrumenty/show_id/*',
    array('controller' => 'instruments', 'action' => 'shows'),
    array('persist' => true)
);
```